# How Do I get Multiple Pictures from Matrix for use in a JQuery LightBox?

Tags: matrix, jquery

I am tring to get Pixel and Tonic's Matrix plugin to deliver images to ColorBox / LightboxI have Matrix delivering single images to my JQuery LightBox ( ColorBox) but I can not get it to deliver multiple images so that I can run them as a slide show.. What am I doing wrong ? Here is the mark up I have so far. My images are all contained in multiple rows but a single column{cell_1}:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="gallery"}
{gallery}
<a class="gallery"  href="{cell_1}">Gallery</a>
{/gallery}
{/exp:channel:entries}

<script>
jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox();
</script>
```

Many  Many Thanks !

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot of your matrix field with a few images populated?

Comment: Also, can you show us what HTML this outputs?

Comment: How do I post a screen shot ?

Comment: @dgrebb How do I post a screen shot ? I can see no upload link.

Comment: Vince try using this: https://droplr.com/hello

Comment: @dgrebb  

Thanks so much for helping out this newb ! I'm not getting very far, very fast ! herer is the link to the image you requested: http://d.pr/i/4yXo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want one text link to open a slideshow of several images in Colorbox, correct?

You'll need to add those colorbox links to the HTML but hide them with CSS. They can be grouped by using the `rel` parameter like `<a href="img.jpg" rel="group1">`

[Here's an example of using the rel attribute with Colorbox](http://jsfiddle.net/alexroper/zHZXR/).

Alternately, you can group them by setting the rel parameter in colorbox like this:

```
$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
```

[Here's an example of that](http://jsfiddle.net/alexroper/zHZXR/2/).

In terms of your EE template code, you could do something like this and add a "hide" class to each link after the first matrix row:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="gallery"}
  {gallery}
    <a class="gallery{if '{row_count}' > 1} hide{/if}" rel="group1" href="{cell_1}">Gallery</a>
  {/gallery}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: HI Alex ! Thanks for helping out - I have my colorbox working in terms of hard coded hrefs. That is not my problem. My problem is that I want to use Pixe and Tonic's "Matrix" to load the images. Then I want to display them using the Matrix tags in EE into a Colorbox slide show. 
I can not get Matrix and Colorbox to co-operate even though it is apparently 'easy' .... or at least so I am told !
Many Thanks !

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Can you edit your original question and add an example of the HTML code that you're getting outputted from your template? If your template tags are working, it might be how the File Manager is configured that's causing the problem.

Comment: Hi Alex - sorry for deplay been away. Thanks for helping out !  here is the html you wanted:
http://d.pr/i/eOvo

I don't think my tags are right in my markup. Here they are: 
http://d.pr/i/bAta

I come from a PHP / CI background and EE is a WHOLE different world ! 

MANY THANKS for helping out a newb to EE ! :o)

Comment: Everything looks great with you EE tag code. I think you just need to put script tag for 'jquery-latest.js' before 'jquery.colorbox.js'. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/alexroper/aKqvw/ Are you getting errors in the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 2):

First, ignore the JS code that makes it work and be sure that you can output multiple images.

Based on your current channel:entries tag you are trying to get an entry from the gallery channel dynamically based on the URL. Is that what you want? Also, you're not outputting any image tags, and is your matrix column really called cell_1?

What do you get when you do this - be sure to replace the starred bits.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="gallery" entry_id="**actual_id_here**"}
  {gallery}
    {**actual_cell_name**}
  {/gallery}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: I can get multiple static images out. However for each image I have a "gallery" link giving a single image. What I want is to be able to offer a single "gallery" link, which will then invoke a slide show in a lightbox. The image cell is called cell_1 ony because I don't have the imagination to call it something else. :o) Using your mark up above I get source output:

<a class="gallery"  href="http://localhost/angelsroofing/cust_images/gallery/field.jpg">Gallery</a>


http://localhost/angelsroofing/cust_images/gallery/field.jpg

Mutliplied by the number of images

Many Thanks !

Comment: Looks like you're getting what you need from EE. It might be a colorbox issue? Based on your above JS, you're missing the `rel` property from colorbox: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Answer (score 1):

You might try embedding the gallery, I've built similar galleries using this method.

My embed template:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
 channel="{embed:listings}" 
 category="{embed:listingcat}" 
 orderby="date" 
 sort="desc" 
 disable="member_data|trackbacks|pagination" 
 dynamic="no"
 }


    <ul class="gallery">
    {gallery_images}
        <li{if row_count == "1"} {/if}>
          <a href="{large}" rel="prettyPhoto[{url_title}]" title="{text}" >
            {exp:imgsizer:size src="{large}" width="160" height="105"}
               <img src="{sized}" width="{width}" height="{height}" alt="{title}" />
            {/exp:imgsizer:size}
        </a></li>
    {/gallery_images}
    </ul>

{/exp:channel:entries}`
```

Embed tag:

```
{embed="_embeds/_category_listings" 
listingcat="{category_id}" 
listings="portfolio"
}
```

Screenshot of the matrix field settings: http://d.pr/i/lSzr

Screenshot of the publish fields: http://d.pr/i/r6ko

HTML output:

```
<ul class="gallery">
    <li class="first"><a title="title" rel="prettyPhoto[invitations1]" href="/images/uploads/portfolio/img1.jpg">
    <img width="160" height="105" alt="Invitations" src="/images/sized/images/uploads/portfolio/img1-160x105.jpg">
    </a></li>
    <li><a title="title" rel="prettyPhoto[invitations1]" href="/images/uploads/portfolio/img2.jpg">
    <img width="160" height="105" alt="Invitations" src="/images/sized/images/uploads/portfolio/img2-160x105.jpg">
    </a></li>
    <li><a title="title" rel="prettyPhoto[invitations1]" href="/images/uploads/portfolio/img3.jpg">
    <img width="160" height="105" alt="Invitations" src="/images/sized/images/uploads/portfolio/img3-160x105.jpg">
    </a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("area[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
    $(".gallery a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({});
});
```

Hope that helps!